# What actually constitutes "offensive" posts?

Tags: discussion

I've flagged a few posts in my time here as "offensive". When comments are flagged, the option is "rude or offensive", which is relatively straightforward. But some of the answers/questions I've flagged as offensive are often what I would consider extremely rude (and generally not an answer, in the case of answers) than necessarily offensive. (I realise that this is probably idiosyncratic, to an extent.)

Thus - is flagging extremely rude, off-topic posts as offensive appropriate (particularly when such posts aren't comments, where "rude" doesn't seem to be stated in the reasons for flagging)?

Comment: well.. in the case of off topic, I'd just VTC. as for general rudeness.. *you* obviously find it offensive, so I don't see why you can't just flag it as offensive

Comment: This is more-or-less answered here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-work/58035#58035

Comment: Also, assuming you're talking about the recent (now-deleted) answer at http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2057/is-the-nine-tails-still-stronger-than-the-eight-tails-even-though-half-of-him-wa/11318#11318, it's probably fine in that kind of case.

Comment: @LoganM: yeah I was referring to that sort of thing.

Comment: No, that answer was **not** abusive. It was low quality, but it was not abusive. The only reason I approved the flags there was because there were other flags which were correct (and I can apparently not mark individual flags are approved or declined).

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Sorry, but I disagree. "You guys are just a bunch of feeling geeks and nerd making a stupid website over some dumb anime show" can easily be construed as harassment. It's clearly phrased in a way that is "inappropriate for respectful discourse" on this site. While I wasn't offended, I don't think it would be unreasonable for someone who was to use this flag. If it is, then it's misnamed and poorly described. The -100 rep penalty is also irrelevant here since the user was a new user with 1 rep who signed up solely to post this answer.

Comment: Oh, I apologize. I actually did not see what the post was originally after it was edited. Theo original post deserved every single offensive flag it got. Sorry for the misunderstanding. @LoganM

Comment: No problem @MadaraUchiha. I didn't realize it was edited, and yes, the edited version, while not an answer, is not offensive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Offensive flags have a very specific and narrow meaning

> ## it is offensive, abusive, or hate speech This question contains
>
> content that a reasonable person would deem inappropriate for
>   respectful discourse.

Abusive flags, like spam flags are red flags. When you a post gains 6 of them, it is deleted, the author is penalized with -100 reputation, and its content feeds into the various anti-spam mechanisms.

Do not abuse the abusive flags (oh the irony!). When in doubt, make a custom flag.

Abusive flags should be kept for active swearing, racism, harassment, and otherwise harmful or hateful. Specifically, posts that target another user, rather than address a specific issue or question are usually abusive.

Flag constructively! -100 penalty hurts!

---

Note that the *original* answer, before it was edited, deserved the offensive flags.

Comment: Thanks - this was helpful. I assume then that extremely rude but not outright abusive posts should just be flagged as "not an answer" and downvoted?

Comment: Yes. Like I said. When in doubt, flag it with a custom flag and explain what you think is wrong with it. I tend to approve nearly all flags, even if not action needs to be taken. The exception is flags which are noise or downright incorrect.